# Promise.race does not resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic2, observable

I'm trying to set up a promise timeout on my ionic 2 application when the server takes too long to respond. My code looks like the following:

```
.
.
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
.
.
  reqNextQuestion(selectedCategories:string[]) : Promise<any>{
    let url             = "xxxxx/user/id/1337";
    let questionPromise = this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(resp => resp.json());

    return Promise.race([questionPromise, this.timeOutReject(5000, 'Service Error')]);
  }

  timeOutReject(durr?: number, errMsg?: string) : Promise<any>{
    let currDurr   = durr   || this.timeOutDurr;
    let currErrMsg = errMsg || this.timeOutMsg;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(currErrMsg)), currDurr);
    });
  }
```

now when I'm firing the following:

```
 this.reqNextQuestion(this.currCatSelection)
        .then(obj => {
           // NEVER REACH THIS POINT
         }).catch(err => {
           // ONLY GETTING HERE
         });
```

I never get the response from the server. It just jumps to the catch block after 5000 ms like I defined before ...

I tested the server before, and it took about 60 ms on avg to get a response.

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Can only assume that some networky thing is going wrong in `this.http.get()` and that http's own timeout is longer than 5 seconds.

Comment: can you see if the http.get request is even started

Comment: Chaining `questionPromise.then(console.log).catch(console.log);` will allow you to see the fate of the HTTP promise.

Comment: Instead of doing this, try using `.timeout` on the observable returned by the call to `http`.

Comment: I'm afraid that your code is working properly... please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uNs0m0?p=preview). I just changed the URL and both the _then_ and the _catch_ work ok. Can you debug in the server side to see if the request gets there? Could you check that the correct protocol is being used (http/https)? is CORS enabled?

Comment: the request is getting to the server, but without a status code in the logs . I will look deeper into the server side code ...